# Solving x'[t]+a*x[t]==0, listing all the solutions, trying to get the value -1x<1 and all corresponding value of a

Tags: programming, filtering

I am Trying to solve x'[t]+a*x[t]==0,x[0]==1, for x with {t,0,10} using NDSolve.

```
Clear[a, x, t]; Flatten[Table[{s = NDSolve[{x'[t] + a*x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 100}];
Table[x[t] /. s, {t, 0, 10}], a}, {a, 0, 10}]]
```

I got a list of x and a.[image: list of values of x]

now I apply `r = Select[%, -1 < # < 1 &]` to select only those x which lie between -1 to 1,
[image: selected list]

Now as there may be repeated values of x, I delete them by using `p = DeleteDuplicates[r]` .
Now , I want to get the values of x and all the corresponding a, including those a as well which correspond to the repeated values of x. How can I do this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not doing `x/.DSolve[{x'[t]+a*x[t]==0, x[0]==1}, x,t]` which gives you `x[t]=E^-(a t)` and you can calculate any desired values of `x[t]` and `a` from that

Comment: because I want to solve Mathieu equation, and using DSolve gives x[t] as a combination of MathieuS , MathieuC , MathieuSPrime, which are not easy to solve. So by using the reasoning of following problem I can solve the Mathieu equation and plot the stability diagram between a and q. That is why I need those a and q for which x is between some limiting value, and I don't want to use inbuilt function to do this.

Comment: I believe this is another example of "the XY problem" which is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem. This happens when a person really wants to solve problem X, but can't, so they create a different problem Y and ask how to solve it without any hint what X is. Readers are puzzled and confused, but start trying to help solve Y, The answers to Y are often of no help at all for solving X. IF there were a way to put a brief very well written description how to avoid this in the posting process description for new users then perhaps we could avoid some of this.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

eqns = {x'[t] + a*x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1};
```

As pointed out by Bill in the comments, for comparison the exact solution is

```
sol1 = DSolve[eqns, x, t][[1]]

(* {x -> Function[{t}, E^(-a t)]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqns /. sol1

(* {True, True} *)

table1 = Table[x[t] /. sol1, {a, 1, 10}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Since there is a parameter in the differential equation, use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)

```
sol2 = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, x, {t, 0, 10}, a, WorkingPrecision -> 45]
```

[image]

Comparing the approximate numeric results with the exact results (see [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html)):

```
table2 = Table[(x[t] /. sol2)[a], {a, 1, 10}, {t, 0, 10}];

table1 - table2 // Chop

(* {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Duplicate values of `x` occur whenever the products of `a` and `t` are identical.

```
table3 = DeleteDuplicates[
  Table[
    {(x[t] /. sol2)[a] // N, a, t},
    {a, 1, 10}, {t, 0, 10}] //
   Flatten[#, 1] &,
  ((Times @@ Rest[#1]) == (Times @@ Rest[#2]) &)]

{{1., 1, 0}, {0.367879, 1, 1}, {0.135335, 1, 2}, {0.0497871, 1, 
  3}, {0.0183156, 1, 4}, {0.00673795, 1, 5}, {0.00247875, 1, 
  6}, {0.000911882, 1, 7}, {0.000335463, 1, 8}, {0.00012341, 1, 
  9}, {0.0000453999, 1, 10}, {6.14421*10^-6, 2, 6}, {8.31529*10^-7, 2,
   7}, {1.12535*10^-7, 2, 8}, {1.523*10^-8, 2, 9}, {2.06115*10^-9, 2, 
  10}, {3.05902*10^-7, 3, 5}, {7.58256*10^-10, 3, 7}, {3.77513*10^-11,
   3, 8}, {1.87953*10^-12, 3, 9}, {9.35762*10^-14, 3, 
  10}, {6.9144*10^-13, 4, 7}, {1.26642*10^-14, 4, 8}, {2.31952*10^-16,
   4, 9}, {4.24833*10^-18, 4, 10}, {1.38879*10^-11, 5, 
  5}, {6.30512*10^-16, 5, 7}, {2.86261*10^-20, 5, 9}, {1.94854*10^-22,
   5, 10}, {5.74949*10^-19, 6, 7}, {1.4236*10^-21, 6, 
  8}, {3.74594*10^-24, 6, 9}, {-5.64139*10^-25, 6, 
  10}, {5.24831*10^-22, 7, 7}, {2.06509*10^-25, 7, 
  8}, {-1.67134*10^-25, 7, 9}, {5.40872*10^-26, 7, 
  10}, {-1.32346*10^-25, 8, 8}, {-1.35923*10^-26, 8, 
  9}, {4.91701*10^-27, 8, 10}, {3.00999*10^-27, 9, 
  9}, {9.54615*10^-28, 9, 10}, {7.64079*10^-28, 10, 10}}
```